# VBA Auto-add the duration to start date to generate the end date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am trying to generate my end date based on the start date and duration in the table. My table are as follows:

[Table column for ID, Task Desc, Start Date, Duration, Planned End Date is A,B,C,D,E respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T82u0.png)

I have tried to run the VBA code as follows but it will only generate the end date when I run the sub. How do I make it as auto-generate? The code are as follows:

```
Sub PlannedEndDate()

Dim userInputDate As Date
Dim duration As Integer
Dim endDate As Date

Dim MyRow As Long

'Start at row 6
MyRow = 6
'Loop untill column A is empty (no task)
While Cells(MyRow, "A").Value <> ""
    'Only if not yet filled in.
    If Cells(MyRow, "E").Value = "" Then
        'Fetch info
        userInputDate = Cells(MyRow, "C").Value
        duration = Cells(MyRow, "D").Value
        endDate = DateAdd("d", duration, userInputDate)
        'Put it back on the sheet
        Cells(MyRow, "E").Value = endDate
    End If
    MyRow = MyRow + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: When do you want it to be generated?  If it is generated as soon as the worksheet is created, you will end up with a lot of cells saying "1 January 1900".  (Could you just put the formula `=C6+D6` into cell E6, etc, and allow the users to overtype the value as necessary, or is the intention that the users will update "Start Date" or "Duration" and you don't want "Planned End Date" to change from when those cells were originally populated?)

Comment: I want the end date to generate each time the start date and duration cell are filled in and if it is possible, I do not want the user to overtype the value populated for the planned end date.

Comment: So, just to be sure of what you are asking, if a user enters a date of 1 January 2017 into cell C10, and then enters a duration of 1000 into cell D10, you want cell E10 to be set to 28 September 2019.  And then, when the user realises that they only meant to put 100 (and not 1000) in cell D10, you want E10 to remain at 28 September 2019?

Comment: I want it to be automate. The end date will auto generate after user input both start date and duration. I read about worksheet_change event. But I got error when I try using Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range). The end date will change if the user change the duration value. Thats what I tried to achieve

Comment: If you want the end date to be updated to reflect the start date / duration from time to time, I think you want to just use a formula of `=IF(OR(C6="",D6=""),"",C6+D6)` in cell E6 and copy it down to all other cells in column E.  Your code as it currently stands (and as you are asking for) will set the value to a constant and then never change it once it is set (because you specifically say `If Cells(MyRow, "E").Value = "" Then`) - which means errors will forever remain errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I recommend that you just use a formula in column E (e.g. E6 would have `=IF(OR(C6="",D6=""),"",C6+D6)`), the following `Worksheet_Change` event possibly does what you have asked for.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim o As Integer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Don't do anything unless something changed in columns C or D
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("C:D")) Is Nothing Then
        'Process all changed cells in columns C and D
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Columns("C:D"))
            With c
                'Ensure that we are on row 6 or later, and
                'column E is empty, and
                'neither column C or column D is empty
                If .Row > 5 And _
                   IsEmpty(Cells(.Row, "E").Value) And _
                   Not (IsEmpty(Cells(.Row, "C").Value) Or IsEmpty(Cells(.Row, "D").Value)) Then
                    'Ensure that column C contains a date, and
                    'column D contains a numeric value
                    If IsDate(Cells(.Row, "C").Value) And _
                       IsNumeric(Cells(.Row, "D").Value) Then
                        'Calculate planned end date
                        Cells(.Row, "E").Value = CDate(Cells(.Row, "C").Value + Cells(.Row, "D").Value)
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that a change to a cell in column C or D will **not** recalculate the value in column E unless you remove the bit that says `IsEmpty(Cells(.Row, "E").Value) And _`.  (But, if you do that, you may as well just use the formula I recommended.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! It works perfectly. Looking at your code, I now understand better on how to integrate the sub code with the worksheet_change event.

Answer (score 0):

I consider your data is like as below

```
ID  Task Description    Start Date    Duration  Planned End Date
1   subtask1            5-Dec-16           5    
2   subtask2            22-Dec-16          6    
3   subtask3            1-Dec-16           33   
4   subtask4           21-Dec-16           12   
5   subtask5           4-Jan-16            6
```

Put the below code in sheet module where you want perform the operation

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 4) And Target.Row >= 2 Then


    If Cells(Target.Row, 3) = vbNullString Or Cells(Target.Row, 4) = vbNullString Then

    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value + Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value
    End If

End If


End Sub
```

It generate the output every time when you enter the data in column start date or Duration.